# Shared Memory - 2D Array

Tags: c, arrays, syntax, shared-memory

I am requesting assistance with a project I am working on. This is a homework assignment for my Operating Systems course. I am not looking for the answer, just a direction or maybe some syntax clarification. We need to read in a shared document (one string per line) into shared memory. Then, we fork processes to check each line to see if it's a palindrome. The part I am getting stuck on is putting a 2d array into shared memory. I will post a code segment of what I have already. I keep getting a seg fault error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int id = 0;
    char (*shmPtr)[3];

    if ((id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1024, IPC_CREAT | 0666) == -1)){
        perror("Failed to create shared memory segment");
        return 1;
    }

    shmPtr = shmat(id, NULL, 0);


    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            shmPtr[i][j] = 'j';
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am sure this is a mess. I am not sure how to declare the array of pointers, how to interact with the file attached to shared memory, etc. Again, I am not looking for an answer but a little syntax clarification and some explanation if anyone is willing. I have been able to store single variables and retrieve those in shared memory, but the array is killing me. I greatly appreciate any assistance in advance.

EDIT: Updated code to Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example taking out file input as my issue seems to be at storing anything in Shared Memory in context of a 2d array. I am convinced it's some syntax I am getting wrong...

Comment: in general, NEVER use the function `feof()` in a while statement.  Suggest reorganizing the code logic to use the returned value from `fgetc()`.  Similar to: `while( EOF != (ch = fgetc( file ) ) )`

Comment: the function `shmat()` returns a `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer, so no need to cast it.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, as this is, post a [mcve]

Comment: `test` needs to be a struct that is defined similar to: `char test[ MAXLINES ][ MAXWORDS ][ MAX_CHAR_PER_WORD];` and associated with the address of the shared memory (I.E. shmptr).

Comment: I modified code to be Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example per your suggestion.

Comment: I removed the error check on the shmget and changed the allocated to size to sizeof(char[3][3]) and finally have it working. Taking it back to the minimum helped to narrow down the issue, so thank you! I still need to work the error checking back in later, but this is a good step.

Comment: this statement: `char (*shmPtr)[3];`  is declaring an array of three pointers to char.  but, the code is treating it as if it were an array of integers.  Suggest: `struct threeInts { int myInts[3]; };  struct threeInts *shmPtr;  shmPtr = shmat(id, NULL, 0);`  then access the integers via: `shmPtr->myInts[j]`